# Java reflection and autoboxing

Tags: java, reflection, autoboxing

I'm using reflection to set field value but when I try to assign Short to short I get error because isAssignable() return false.

```
private void setFieldValue(Object result, Field curField, Object value) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    if (!curField.getType().isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
        LOG.error("Can't set field value type mismatch: field class: " + curField.getType().getSimpleName() + ", value class: " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
    } else {
        curField.set(result, value);
    }
}
```

any clues how can I make reflection to do autoboxing?

Comment: [ClassUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ClassUtils.html#isAssignable%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20boolean%29) might be of help here.

Comment: The Field will accept the boxed value (since it's the only way to use it). I don't know why `isAssignableFrom` is programmed this way.

Comment: @Danny your right! works perfectly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an `int` field `getType` will return `int.class`.  This has been the case since before auto-
boxing was introduced to Java and so, correctly, if you're preserving backward compatibility, `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)` returns `false` when the object type is passed the primitive type.

Or as in your case:

```
int.class.isAssignableFrom(int.class)
```

would return `true`, while:

```
int.class.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)
```

would return `false`.

The quick fix it to write a method that when presented with the object type, checks for the that type and the primitive or use the classes in libraries like Jakarta Commons ([ClassUtils.isAssignable(Class, Class, boolean)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ClassUtils.html#isAssignable%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20boolean%29)).

Comment: yep, if you update ClassUtils.isAssignable(Class, Class, boolean) I'll accept answer :D

Comment: `ClassUtils.isAssignable(Class, Class)` does the same as `ClassUtils.isAssignable(Class, Class, boolean)` when you pass `true`

Comment: didn't work with Class, Class only when I used boolean version with boolean set to true, maybe other version has different defaults, this is 2.6 apache commons.

Comment: Ah yes, just looked at the source, I've confused what widening means - it'll say a `long` is assignable from an `int`, which is different to autoboxing - nice spot

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually check for whether the value is possibly a wrapper for a primitive type, and make special cases for all the primitive types. Sounds like a pain, use a lib as @Danny suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if one (and only one) class is a primitive (Class#isPrimitive()). If yes check for autoboxing use a switch. Since there is no subclassing involved, you can just write a helper method where the primitive class is first and the other second. This way it is just 8 comparisons for compensating so you will not need an additional dependency.